# Let $x_0$ be an extreme point of $f$ and $g$. Is $x_0$ an extreme point of $\max\{f,g\}$?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, extreme-value-analysis

> Let $x_0$ be an local extreme point of $f$ and $g$. Is $x_0$ an local extreme point of $\max\{f,g\}$?

Let $x_0$ is the local maximum point of $f$ and $g$, it is OK! What may happen if $x_0$ is the local minimum point of $f$, and the local maximum point of $g$?

Comment: I suppose this is about *local* extrema?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes.

Comment: Any assumptions on continuity?

Comment: Is $x_0$ really a point, or is it the x-coordinate of what might be two different extreme points?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think this proposition is wrong. But I could not such an example.

Comment: @MatthewDaly $x_0$ is the x-coordinate of what might be two different extreme points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, $f,g$ are not required to be continuous.
Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2&x=x_0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1&x<x_0\\0&x=x_0\\3&x>x_0\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ has a local maximum and $g$ a local minimum at $x_0$. However,
$$\max\{f,g\}(x)=\begin{cases}1&x<x_0\\2&x=x_0\\3&x>x_0\end{cases}$$
does not have an extremum at $x_0$.

Comment: It would be easy to modify this to use continuous functions...